# In Judges 9:8-15, how did the trees talk?

Tags: judges

In Judges 9:8-15, Jotham conveys a message about the trees speaking amongst themselves while seeking a king. Since I understand Jotham to be a prophet, he is presumably relaying a message from God. Perhaps I am mistaken, and he is not a prophet. But then, how can he claim that God will listen to the people if they listen to him (Jotham)?

Since there are several examples of non-human speech in the Bible that people believe to be literal historical events, it is not immediately clear that Jotham is not also speaking of a literal historical event. If the trees really did seek a king, how did they talk without the anatomical structures to do so? If not, by what principles can the event be identified as fiction?

Comment: You forgot to take Judges 9:7 into account: Jotham is recounting a [fable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fable), **not** a prophetic oracle. It pays to understand genre distinctions.

Comment: -1 Sorry about that, xiota. Your question is interesting, but not so clear. You are mixing up Jotham's authority as a prophet with trees talking. On the other hand, your question does not show any research effort or even a careful reading of the biblical text in question. Last but not least, it is always useful to provide the biblical text in question and to take into account the BH suggestions on [how to ask a question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 2):

The incident in Judges 9:8-15 is clearly a clever imaginative parable, as such, is one of many in the OT.  For example:

- Judges 9:7-15 - Trees call for a king
- 2 San 12:1-4 - Poor man's ewe lamb
- 2 Sam 14:1 - Two brothers striving
- 1 Kings 20:35-40 - Smitten prophet
- 2 Kings 14:9 - The Thistle and the Cedar
- Isa 5:1-6 - Isaiah's parable of the vineyard
- Eze 24:3-5 - The boiling pot
- Eze 17:3-10 - Great eagle and the vine
- Eze 19:2-9 - Lion's Whelps

There are many more!  It was this rich tradition of parable telling that Jesus drew upon to tell His parables; all of which had the effect of teaching important spiritual and moral principles.  The example in Judges is no exception.

Comment: For more on OT parables see:  https://www.scribd.com/document/328697500/PARABLES-in-the-OLD-TESTAMENT-CONTEXT-pdf  http://www.lookinguntojesus.info/BSTopics/Parables/PARABLES-OT.html  https://newchristianbiblestudy.org/bundles/ncbsw/on-deck/english/books/Parables%20OT%20-%20Mitchell.html  and many more.  Hope this is helpful.

Comment: It is usually quite obvious.  Recall that parables can be either spoken or enacted as in Ezekiel's enacted parables (eg, Eze 4).  The usual clue is the function of the story - is it to teach some moral or spiritual lesson as distinct from just recounting history as per Acts 7.  If the former, it is almost always a parable.  See the previous lists for better examples.

Comment: @xiota, a fairly good guide is to apply the same common sense you would use in everyday speech.  If a friend tells you "My heart is broken," you recognize the common metaphor -- so you know that he very likely means he is in deep sorrow (and does not mean literal damage to his physical heart).  But if he says "My leg is broken," this is not a common metaphor for anything: so you know he most likely does mean literal damage to his physical leg.  Spend some time studying the Bible and you will learn its common metaphors and learn to recognize them.